# How does Apache Derby deal with empty list in WHERE IN () clause

Tags: sql, derby, where-in, javadb

Hi this sql statement excutes as expected

```
select * from table where id in(1,2,3);
```

But there is posibility of IN() clause to be empty like below

```
    select * from table where id in();
```

Apache Derby complains with 
`syntax error : encountered ")" at line n`

Mysql knows how to deal with such a situation and will return no value, How do i make apache derby act the same as mysql when it comes to such empty list?

Comment: `IN ()` is invalid SQL and will be rejected by any self-respecting database. MySQL is known to not really care about proper SQL syntax. You should fix your code to generate valid SQL statements.